# Jquery: Control the values ​inside an array in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a loop in the html document that makes the input for me,

```
foreach (var prosize in productsize)
    {
        <span class="stylesize js-size">@prosize</span>
        <input type="checkbox" class="js-choosesize" value="@prosize" />

    }
```

Jquery :

```
 const sizes = [];
            Pform.find('.js-choosesize:checked').each(function (i) {
                sizes[i] = $(this).val();
            });
```

in browser :

```
    <span class="stylesize js-size">36</span>
    <input type="checkbox" class="js-choosesize" value="36">
    <span class="stylesize js-size">37</span>
    <input type="checkbox" class="js-choosesize" value="37">
    <span class="stylesize js-size">38</span>
    <input type="checkbox" class="js-choosesize" value="38">
```

First: I want the number of inputs to be controlled, that is, if the user increases or decreases the element with "Inspect-Element", This will be controlled?

Second: If the user changes the values ​​with the "Inspect-Element" or enters a duplicate value, the duplicate values ​​will be recorded in the object only once.

Comment: what is "Inspect-Element"? What does "controlled" mean?

Comment: @Tomalak Control `sizes[]`values

Comment: You need to reconsider your security requirements.  Anything the browser can do, a user an do manually, eg `$(".js-choosesize").first().val("31")` - there are ways to "watch" DOM changes, but they're not security.  eg `function checkForChanges() { ... your code to check for changes ... }` can quickly become:  `function checkForChanges() { return false; }` via the console.

Comment: @freedomn-m Can you give an example with the code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-javascript-jquery-dom-change-listener

Answer (score 0):

I Used This Code

```
 Frm_AddProduct.on('DOMSubtreeModified', function () {
            location.reload();
            console.log('changed');
        });
```

This is a good solution, but in terms of security, I do not know if it is good or not